# Add language to control

Tags: orbeon

Is there a way to add to easily add text for a not included language to a control that is included in Orbeon, ie what having to recompile Orbeon / contribute and wait for new release? In particular, adding "Please Select:" in another language for select components.

I have seen http://doc.orbeon.com/contributors/localizing-orbeon-forms.html, but was hoping there was a way such as adding it to a property in properties-local that could speed up the process.

Comment: Have also just noticed that you don't seem to be able to achieve a quick win in adding a button label in a unsupported(?) language either (eg trying to add a Welsh label for the wizard buttons). Is this to be expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The localizations for a XBL controls are embedded in the XBL file itself. So no unfortunately there is no way to override these via properties at this point.

For adding a new language to Form Runner, you also need to add that language to the Form Runner `resources.xml` file. Adding resources via properties can only patch existing Form Runner resources, but not create new ones. That is a limitation which, in theory, could be lifted, with some work.